# Mysql max function with specific value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

I have following table structure for `tTable`

```
id | version | parentId
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 2
4  | 1       | 3
5  | 2       | 3
6  | 3       | 3
```

If I execute

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS maxId, FROM tTable GROUP BY parentId
```

then it will return below result.

```
id | version | parentId
1  | 1       | 1
3  | 2       | 2
6  | 3       | 3
```

But here I would like to a little change in returned result for example I would like to have following result set with max() in tTable.

```
id | version | parentId
1  | 1       | 1
3  | 2       | 2
*5 | 2       | 3*
```

**id = 5th record**. I would like to get other two records with max(id) but want to get different id (I want to provide condition) for parentId = 3.

Is it possible in max() with any condition. I would like to preserve other max id but want only change in specific record?

**Edit:**

Here 5 (or may be 4) will be coming from dynamic variable. So in case of parentId = 3 there could be any value for id (may be 4 or 5 or 6).

Comment: So how do you want to change it? Is there any logic behind picking 5 instead of 6?

Comment: I don't know that's why asking for alternate solution. I am not telling to implement only with max. May be here all of you friends have some other solution ! :)

Comment: But you must explain what the logic behind picking 5 instead of 6. Otherwise you can just change the query to: `SELECT MAX(id) AS maxId, FROM tTable WHERE id != 6 GROUP BY parentId` and you will never get 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to get the result you want but that may not be a exact solution. thought of putting it once if it helps. See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78cde/9

```
(SELECT MAX(id) AS maxId, version, parentId 
FROM tTable 
WHERE parentId != 3
GROUP BY parentId)

union all

(SELECT id as maxId, version, parentId 
FROM tTable 
WHERE parentId = 3
order by maxId desc
limit 1,1)
```